# Why T480s screen takes time to change contrast when switching between black and white apps

Tags: display, thinkpad

I'm not sure how to word this properly. But I noticed that my Thinkpad T480s (and X1 Carbon Gen 5) takes some times to reach whiteness when switching apps. It seems like the screen also struggles with gradient background, it will flickers for a few second before reaching stable state.

I googled this and many people said turning off Adaptive brightness would help. But for me that is not the case. In Windows Power options, Adaptive brightness is off.

Comment: Some screens have these issues. Things you can try are: download and install ALL the latest drivers from the support website. Make sure Windows is up to date. If that doesn't work, then you should contact support if the laptop is under warranty.

Comment: It's weird because I own several thinkpad and this happens on all of them. So I'm thinking it might be intentional?

Comment: They are all IPS displays btw

Comment: Did you purchase these new? If so, were these symptoms evident from the first or did they appear over time? The same deleterious behavior occurring on several systems of the same model typically indicates a hardware design issue (though, a driver issue could still be the cause, though that would be easily tested and remedied if it were so). Basically, this comes back to the suggestions I made in my first comment. Please follow those steps and report their success or failure.

Comment: Same here, especially when I watch a movie/video with dark image and that makes the image even less visible. It takes few seconds to go back to full brightness when I close the video. It's definitely something I'll check for my future laptop, it's been annoying for years.

Answer (score 2):

I understood this is an years old question. In case somebody come here for the same problem, here is what I did to solve my case.

If your case meeting the following descriptions, this may be caused by [Intel Display Power Saving Technology](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln309126/?lang=en) getting involved and trying to reduce the overall power consumption.

- Only occurred when powered by battery.
- Only occurred when switching between dark themed app and light one.
- Came with an Intel Graphics Card.
- Has Intel Graphics Control Panel installed.
- Windows operating system.

To disable it, go to Intel Graphics Control Panel > Power > On battery, unchecked the Intel Display Power Saving Technology option and save.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! This answer must be accepted. Unbelievable they enable that sh** by default... we all think it's a laptop problem. On windows' settings, Battery:"Maximum performance" didn't disable it... we have to go to the intel app for that.